# javafx image remove from imageview

Tags: javafx, imageview

I have a grid-pane containing many ImageView nodes. When clicking on an ImageView, I want to remove the image.

```
 ImageView image = new ImageView("https://www.google.co.in/images/nav_logo242.png");
```

On an action, I did:

```
 image.setImage(null);
 System.gc();
```

But, I still see the older image.

```
 image.getImage(); // it returns null
```

Comment: Post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The last time I tested it, this code worked. (Even if "I still see th older image" means "the image is present in memory")

Comment: You don't need to call `System.gc()`.

Answer (score 6):

This should work:

```
image.setImage(null);
```

post your whole code to check errors.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem

```
image.setCache(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gridPane.getChildren().remove(image);
```

Comment: I can't remove the grid, because I have associated an event with the grid. e.g. I have created an grid then on left click an image is set to grid and on right click image is removed from the grid. again once the image is removed we can set an image, similarly once the image is set to grid we can replace the image with another on left click to grid. So if we remove the grid, all event will be lost

Answer (score 0):

This implementation is quite functional I recommend if you are going to delete several nodes or imageViews make a list of the same type and then just add them to the list and when you are going to delete them just go through the FOR deleting by imageView by position.

List statement.

```
ArrayList<ImageView> listaImageView2 = new ArrayList<>();
```

Implementation to eliminate each elimination.

```
for (int i = 0; i < listaImageView2.size(); i++) {
       listaImageView2.get(i).imageProperty().set(null);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
ImageView.imageProperty().set(null);
```

This is perfectly working for me

Comment: Added to the answer, it's always a good idea to explain why this works in your answer. Also please use `code formatting` to format the code segments correctly

Answer (score -1):

you could simply replace the current image with an empty image with 1 px width and height

```
image.setImage(new Image("path to your empty image"));
```

Comment: Since `null` is a valid value for the `image` property, this approach will only increase the number of objects used. It also increases the size of the `ImageView` which won't be noticeable in most cases, but may be in some. Probably the op does something like `image.addListener(ActionEvent.ANY, evt -> { ... });` to register the event handler which does not work since `ImageView` does not provide any properties of type `EventHandler<ActionEvent>`. The OP never posted a [mcve] though so it's impossible to tell...